# Client requests accepted every third attemt?

Tags: java, sockets, server, tcpclient

I'm building a TCP server. I'm using TelNet to connect a client to the server. The server has a worker method that handles the request. In the handle method, I pass the clients inputs (this works) and see if it matches my given protocols. Strangely the if statement only picks up the first command, then only every third.

Code EX:

```
    out = new PrintWriter(this.client.getOutputStream(), true);

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.client.getInputStream()));

    String read;

    while(!(read = in.readLine()).equals("Bye")) 
    {

        if(read.equals("getTime")) //M1 Method
        {
            out.println(Worker.time());
            //read = in.readLine();

        }
        else if(read.equals("Punch"))
        {
            out.println("you've been punched");
            //read = in.readLine();
        }

    }
```

I assumed that every time the input is set with a value I have to reset it (the commented lines in each method).

Terminal OutPut:

gsp19 319 % telnet localhost 1024

Trying 127.0.0.1...

Connected to localhost.

Escape character is '^]'.

getTime
Mon Sep 10 15:05:38 EDT 2018

getTime
getTime
getTime
Mon Sep 10 15:05:43 EDT 2018

getTime
getTime
getTime
Mon Sep 10 15:05:48 EDT 2018

getTime
getTime
getTime
Mon Sep 10 15:05:54 EDT 2018

Punch
Punch
Bye
You've been disconnected.

Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: What do you see when you print out the command at the top of your while body ? `System.out.println("Got line |" + read + "|");`  (Note the | symbols there, so you can see if there's any whitespace characters before or after the line )

Comment: the line is get is:
Got line |getTime|

There's no white spaces which is what I want

Comment: Eclipse has been really frustrating... I took a break for a half hour, got back to the code and everything works.